# Trying to do integration using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

prove using residue theorem $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos2\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}d\theta={\pi}/6$$
I tried by using $$z=e^{i\theta}$$
now $$\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}$$
$$dz=izd\theta$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos2\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2\cos^2\theta-1}{5+4\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^4+1)dz}{2iz^2(2z+1)(z+2)}$$
Now poles occur at $$z=0, -1/2, -2$$
rejecting $$z=-2,$$as $$ |z|=2>1$$
Now $$Res_{z=-1/2}=\frac{(-1/2)^4+1)}{2i(-1/2)^2(-1/2+2)}=17/12i$$
Pole at z=0 is  of order 2
$$Res_{z=0}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{dz}(\frac{(z^4+1)}{2i(2z+1)(z+2)})=-5/8i$$
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos2\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}d\theta={2\pi}i(Res_{z=-1/2}+Res_{z=0})=19{\pi}/12$$
But the answer is $${\pi}/6$$
I tried many times, but i get the same answer

Comment: the integral around the unit circle does not include a contour along the real axis from 0 to $2\pi$, so I cannot see why you are equating those two integrals

Comment: Is the answer really $\pi/6??$

Comment: The integrand is $\frac{z^4+1}{iz^2(3z+1)(z+3)}$ and the answer is $\pi/18$...

Comment: If you'll do it without residue theorem, performing the half angle tangent substitution then the answer will come $\pi/18$

Comment: if you just sovle it otherwise $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos2\theta}{5+3\cos\theta}d\theta$$ simply treating it as  a definite integral the answer comes out to be $${\pi}/6$$ but i can't prove the same using residue method

Comment: @Gowhar1998 fhe answer is $\pi/18$

Comment: Did you misspell "theorem" because you were told a post with that title already existed? Then you should try to come up with a better title, not misspell it so that it is difficult to find later.

Comment: Even if you suppose $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^4+1)dz}{2iz^2(2z+1)(z+2)}$ is the right step, you aren't calculating the residue at $z=-1/2$ correctly. When you take the limit as $z \to -1/2$, you should cancel out the $(2z+1)$ with an extra $1/2$ that comes from it. So the residue should come out to be $\frac{17}{24i}$.

Comment: @Accelerator, thanks for pointing this out, finally $${2\pi}i(Res_{z=-1/2}+Res_{z=0})={2\pi}i(17/24i -5/8i)=π/6$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^4+1)dz}{2iz^2(2z+1)(z+2)}$, should be converted to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1+z^4}{4z^2(z+2)(z+1/2)}$. From there, you can see you have poles at $z=-2$, $z=0$ (order $2$), and $z=-\dfrac{1}{2}$. Since we only care about the poles inside the unit circle, we can evaluate the two resides as follows:

$$2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+z^4}{4z^2(z+2)(z+1/2)}, z=0\right) = \frac{2\pi i}{(2-1)!}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}\frac{(z-0)^2\left(1+z^4\right)}{4z^2(z+2)(z+1/2)} = -\frac{10\pi i}{8}$$

and

$$2\pi i\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+z^4}{4z^2(z+2)(z+1/2)}, z=-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = 2\pi i \lim_{z\to -1/2}\frac{\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+z^{4}\right)}{4z^{2}\left(z+2\right)\left(z+1/2\right)} = \frac{34\pi i}{24}.$$

Therefore, the integral is

$$\frac{1}{i}\left(\frac{34\pi i}{24}-\frac{10\pi i}{8}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}.$$

Comment: But the answer is three times that. Did you leave out the factor of three on purpose?

Comment: @KamalSaleh The OP is claiming the answer is $\pi/6$, but the answer is $\pi/18$.

Comment: Oh yes reading the comments on the OP clears things up. +1 for your detailed answer.

Comment: Sounds good! I'm glad your confusion got cleared up. @KamalSaleh

Comment: @Accelerator, thanks for this answer but there was a slight error in my attempt you pointed earlier in your comment

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contribution

Comment: @Gowhar1998 the integral in question is not equal to $\pi/6$. Why did you edit this answer?

Comment: Do you want to explain [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+cos%282x%29%2F%285%2B3cosx%29+from+0+to+2pi) then? @Gowhar1998

Comment: @Gowhar1998 I'm not sure what sources support your claim, but I verified my original answer numerically when I uploaded my original answer. I'm not sure how your edit got approved too.

Comment: @Accelerator, I would like to apologize for the mistake I made in providing you with the wrong question to solve. I understand that this may have caused confusion and wasted your valuable time. Please accept my sincerest apologies for any inconvenience this may have caused. I will make sure to double-check my work in the future to prevent similar mistakes from happening again.it was $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos2\theta}{5+4\cos\theta}d\theta={\pi}/6$$

Comment: I wanted to reach out and apologize for my mistake in providing you with the wrong question to solve. I realize now that my error has caused confusion and frustration, and I am truly sorry for any inconvenience that I may have caused.I understand that your time is valuable, and I should have been more careful in ensuring that the information I provided was accurate, Though I have  corrected it now
Once again, I apologize for any inconvenience that I have caused and hope that you can accept my sincere apology.